# MacBook Pro dies overnight

Tags: macbook

I have a 2009 MacBook and if it is not connected to power, it will die overnight. Battery cycle count is 60.

Can this behavior be changed to go to "deep sleep" after 30 minutes of inactivity wherein it stops draining the battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to get your computer to an Apple Certified technician so they can run the battery diagnostic on your machine.

If you still want to manually adjust the hibernation time on your computer, [then there are a few articles on the subject](http://www.google.com/search?&q=macbook+hibernation). From Apple's own discussions I [found this](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2349834&tstart=-1).

Comment: Almost. These pages led me to: http://www.jinx.de/SmartSleep.html which is a compromise.

Although is seems the feature I'm seeking is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For optimum battery life perhaps try the following:

1. Go to Energy Saver in System Preferences
2. Click on the Battery Tab
3. Make sure all three checkboxes are
   checked (put hard disk to sleep,
   slightly dim display, automatically
   reduce brightness
4. Change Sleep Display time to
   something low
5. **change Computer Sleep to 30 minutes**

Comment: sleep is what I want to avoid